# Typescript: Can't extend Express Request

Tags: typescript, express

Why is Typescript NOT extending the Request object? I'm beyond frustrated trying to get this to work..

Declare the type.. after installing the @types/Express package..

```
// global.d.ts

declare namespace Express {
  interface Request {
    user: string;
  }
}
```

```
(req, res) => {
  const user = req.user
}
```

`Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Request'`

WHY? WHY? WHY?

Answer (score 3):

I created a `@types` folder to my project and added the following code:

`@types/express/index.d.ts`

```
import { Express } from "express-serve-static-core";

declare module "express-serve-static-core" {
    interface Request {
        user: {
            ... user.x here ... 
        }
    }
}
```

You can now extend `user` from `Request`

Answer (score 0):

The main error is you are declaring user as a String, simply changing its type may work for you.

```
declare namespace Express {
  interface Request {
    user: {
      // user fields here
    };
  }
}
```